# Difference between startActivity and startActivites

Tags: android, android-activity

There are these two:

```
startActivities (Intent[] i, Bundle b) = API level 16
startActivity (Intent i, Bundle b) = API level 16
```

Not Interested in these since they are used for backward compatibility (I guess)

```
startActivities (Intent[] i) = API level 11
startActivity (Intent i ) = API level 1
```

I have also looked at the source and I have read the Android Doc Reference, but didn't fully grasp it.

What is the difference between `Activity.startActivity` and `Activity.startActivities` and what are they used for (examples)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
startActivities (Intent[] i, Bundle b)
```

starts a list of activities using the `Intents`  array `i` (used to launch several activities at once)

```
startActivity (Intent i, Bundle b)
```

start a single activity

The diference between the versions that accept the `Bundle` and the ones without it is that they allow for you to provide the 
`ActivityOptions` when start starting the `Activity` which are used for some activity Transitions and animations

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html

Comment: So when you start the multiple activities, what are the lifecycles like, does the second activity start only if the first activity is destroyed?

Comment: You can check it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities(android.content.Intent[], android.os.Bundle), but what it does is basically launches them in the order they are in the array so you will have the last one visible and by pressing back you go to the previous

Comment: So the best place to use this would be to launch consecutive activities, but they shouldn't be dependant on each other(apparently it throws an exception)

Comment: Yes if the creation of an activity on position n + 1 depends on the activity n being created (`onCreate`) being called then no. What you mean with "apparently it throws an exception" ? are you refering to the `ActivityNotFoundException` ?

Comment: Yes I think they are bringing attention to the multiple activities lifecycle. I think...